# Apex Code for Campaign Member List

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, campaign, campaign-member

I've been struggling with creating code (I am not a developer) for a VP where all Campaign Members with certain fields completed (CampaignMember.Article_Link__c) are displayed in a table.

The goal is to have this information display for each company the campaign is for. The table shows up fine, but I can't figure out how to query the information correctly. Searching other people's code and trying to adapt for my needs isn't working; I always get a "illegal from list to list" error.

**Apex**

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign" extensions="CampaignMembers">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CampaignMember}" var="member">
<apex:column headerValue="Date">
<apex:outputfield value="{!CampaignMember.FirstRespondedDate}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Source">
<apex:outputfield value="{!CampaignMember.Source__c}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Outlet">
<apex:outputfield value="{!CampaignMember.CompanyOrAccount}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Placement">
<apex:outputfield value="{!CampaignMember.Article_Link__c}"/>
</apex:column>
    
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
 
</apex:page>
```

**Class**

```
public with sharing class CampaignRelatedListExtension
{
    public List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers { get; set; }
    public List<Campaign> Campaign { get; set; }
    public CampaignRelatedListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        CampaignMembers = [
            SELECT CampaignMember.FirstRespondedDate, CampaignMember.Source__c, CampaignMember.CompanyorAccount, CampaignMember.Article_Link__c FROM CampaignMember
        ];  
}
 }
```

Apex that works:
[image]

Goal:
Tab: Company #1: date, source, outlet, link (20 records)
Tab: Company #2: date, source, outlet, link (10 different records), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign" extensions="CampaignMembers">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CampaignMember}" var="member">
         <apex:column headerValue="Date">
            <apex:outputfield value="{!CampaignMember.FirstRespondedDate}"/>
         </apex:column>

         ...

       </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

1. The extensions attribute must reference the classname of the extensions, hence it should be:

   ```
   <apex:page standardController="Campaign" extensions="CampaignRelatedListExtension">
   ```
2. The pageBlockTable value property must refer to a collection in the Controller so it should be

   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!campaignMembers}" var="member">
3. The columns need to reference the pageBlocvkTable var attribute so they should look like:

   ```
   <apex:column headerValue="Date">
       <apex:outputfield value="{!member.FirstRespondedDate}"/>
    </apex:column>
   ```
4. The query you have in the controller fetches all possible CampaignMembers as you don't have a WHERE clause:

   ```
   public CampaignRelatedListExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
      CampaignMembers = [
       SELECT CampaignMember.FirstRespondedDate, CampaignMember.Source__c, CampaignMember.CompanyorAccount, CampaignMember.Article_Link__c 
       FROM CampaignMember
      ];  
     }
   ```

It is not exactly clear from your question what your WHERE clause should be but if you are looking for only CampaignMembers where Article_Link__c is non null then you would do:

```
SELECT CampaignMember.FirstRespondedDate, CampaignMember.Source__c, CampaignMember.CompanyorAccount, CampaignMember.Article_Link__c 
FROM CampaignMember
WHERE Article_Link__c != NULL
```

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS, thank you so much! I cannot express to you the importance of your assistance, and truly breaking down where the issues were. You helped a ton (over a week of trying to figure it out on my own) and I've also learned a lot. Thank you, thank you, thank you!